# How to use gmail in smtpJS

Tags: javascript, smtp, gmail, smtpjs

When trying to use Gmail in smtpJS, I get the message "Only elasticemail is supported as an SMTP host". Is this a new rule or am I doing something wrong? It seems to have worked before. The code is same as in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

as you can see now only Elastic Email is allowed as a reliable host with smtpjs so you have to create an account at first to use it. You can create a new account [here](https://elasticemail.com/account#/create-account?product=api) and use a free trial of up to 100 emails/day. For more, you have to pay.